# Oracle11g-x64-ent install on SUSE Linux have many check errors

Tags: linux, 64-bit, oracle11g, suse

I have searched  much materials,but dint got answer. please give some tips,thanks !!

Oracle11g-x64-ent 11.1.0.6.0,

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP2 (x86_64),

the envirement set by:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle/dttest/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.1.0/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/usr/lib
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Oracle installer check results are:

```
Checking operating system requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CertifiedVersions' from ruleset 'OSChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczOSChecks.checkCertifiedOSVersions' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: Make sure you are installing the software on the correct platform.
========================================================

Checking operating system package requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CheckPackages' from ruleset 'PackagesChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczPackagesChecks.checkPackages' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: Install the required packages before continuing with the installation.
========================================================

Checking kernel parameters
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CheckParameters' from ruleset 'KernelChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczKernelChecks.checkParameters' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: Perform operating system specific instructions to update the kernel parameters.
========================================================

Checking Recommended glibc version
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CheckGLIBC' from ruleset 'GLIBCChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczGlibcChecks.checkGlibc' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: You may actually have installed packages which have obsoleted these, in which case you can successfully continue with the install. If you have not, it is recommended that you do not continue. Refer to the product release notes to find out how to get the missing packages and update the system.
========================================================

Checking physical memory requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CheckPhysicalMemory' from ruleset 'SystemChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczSystemChecks.checkPhysicalMemory' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: Increase the amount of physical memory available to your system before continuing with the installation.
========================================================

Checking available swap space requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CheckSwapSpace' from ruleset 'SystemChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczSystemChecks.checkSwapSpace' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: Make more swap space available to perform the install.
========================================================

Checking Network Configuration requirements ...
Actual Result: :java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: "18446744073709551615"
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
Recommendation: Oracle supports installations on systems with DHCP-assigned public IP addresses.  However, the primary network interface on the system should be configured with a static IP address in order for the Oracle Software to function properly.  See the Installation Guide for more details on installing the software on systems configured with DHCP.
========================================================

Checking PATH environment variable...
Actual Result: :java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: "18446744073709551615"
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
Recommendation: Restart the installer after removing other ORACLE_HOME locations from PATH environment variable.
========================================================

Checking for sufficient diskspace in TEMP location...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed
========================================================

Checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable...
Actual Result: :java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: "18446744073709551615"
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
Recommendation: Restart the installer after removing other ORACLE_HOME locations from LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
========================================================

Validating ORACLE_BASE location (if set) ...
Actual Result: :java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: "18446744073709551615"
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
Recommendation: Unset the environment variable 'ORACLE_BASE' or make sure it is specified as a parent of the Oracle home directory.
========================================================

Checking Oracle Home path for spaces...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed
========================================================

Checking for proper system clean-up....
Actual Result: :java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: "18446744073709551615"
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
Recommendation: You must completely remove the ASM instance by deleting the entry for it from the oratab file, or you must configure it properly by ensuring that the oratab file is updated to point to a valid Oracle Home where ASM is configured.
========================================================

Checking for Oracle Home incompatibilities ....
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-15038: Unable to execute rule 'CheckCompatibility' from ruleset 'CompatibilityChecks'. The underlying test 'oracle.sysman.oip.oipc.oipcz.OipczCompatibilityChecks.checkProductCompatibility' has thrown an unhandled exception [For input string: "18446744073709551615"]. If the exception results in a failure of the test and the exception needs to be propagated, then encapsulate the exception in the result object and return the result.
Recommendation: Choose a new Oracle Home for installing this product.
========================================================
```

Comment: This question is not about development, but Oracle installation, and thus belongs on Serverfault.com or SuperUser.com

Comment: Have you started the installer with the right permissions ?

Comment: Thanks , I have posted to Serverfault.com;

the runInstaller  was set by chmod 777.

Answer (score 1):

OUI (Java installer) seems to run on a Java 32 bits so It is unable to retrieve high values as  `SHMMAX` that some GNU/Linux set as an 64bit *-1* to big for a 32bit integer.

```
Set at /etc/sysctl.conf
    kernel.shmmax = 4294967295

/sbin/sysctl -p
```

**Note: this is for maximum block for each share block segment and not a sum of shared memory used for a process or system.**